# Filter result by multiple parameters with different combinations

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table with column A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H

I want to search data with A,B,C,H field. The field parameters can be different combination (2^4=16).The general process if else block is very ugly and slow process and huge code. What technique can i follow to do this with sort line of code effectively?

Comment: where is your codes or where is example column data !

Answer (score 0):

You can let Laravel build your query like so:

```
    if($searchA)
        $ABCDE = $ABCDE->where('A', $A);
    if($searchB)
        $ABCDE = $ABCDE->where('B', $B);
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: if,if,..........; I have to use max 2^4=16 if else condition,because user can input different combination in different time like a,b,c,h,ab,ac,ah,abc...........

Comment: you don't have to make all of the combinations, you just add the column to the where if the column is set to be searched.
i mean there will be just 4 IF statements.